# PHP help with preg_match patterns and regex

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

This is the heart of my plugin that I've been painstakingly developing. Though I've ran into some trouble with the patterns..

```
<?php

$s = '
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="single2" name="single2" src="http://api.realitylapse.com/player.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" flashvars="file=http://cerium.realitylapse.com/stream/bea352a230ebd36b52dc27d874f41f5a/4e3c5eca/default/xxxxx/xxxxx-lq.mp4&amp;plugins=ltas&amp;ltas.cc=inhldvymihzxqln&amp;provider=http" height="424" width="659">

<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.xxxxx.com/player9397/player.swf?" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="provider=http&amp;file=http://www.xxxxx.com/player9397/vb.php?id=TT175YivmF4y&amp;type=video&amp;backcolor=111111&amp;frontcolor=cccccc&amp;lightcolor=DE4949&amp;stretching=fill" height="420" width="99%">

<embed src="http://www.megavideo.com/v/xxxxxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="438">    
';


$patterns = array();
//$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+src=["\']+flashvars=["\'](.*?)["\']'; //Tried this one, but it only works with Cerium and without the pattern below it.
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';   //Too greedy..? Without it, ones like megavideo wont be grabbed.
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';  
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+flashvars="(.+?)["\']'; //Possible problem..
$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+file=(.+?)[&]';         //
$patterns[] = '<iframe[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<iframe[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<object[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<object[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<video[^>]+src=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<video[^>]+data=["\'](.+?)["\']';
$patterns[] = '<video[^>]+file=(.+?)[&]';



$patterns = "#(?:" . implode("|", $patterns) . ")#si";

preg_match_all($patterns, ($s), $m);
//var_dump($m);
if (!empty($m[0]))
{ 
    $edata = array();
    foreach($m[0] as $match)
    { 

//Embeds:
if (preg_match('#realitylapse.com/stream/(.+?)[&,"\']#si', $match, $id))
     $edata[] = "<!--nextpage--><!--tab_title:CERIUM-->\n[cerium " . $id[1] . "]";

else if (preg_match('#http&amp;file=http://www.xxxx.com/player9397/vb.php?id=(.+?)[&,"\']#si', $match, $id))
     $edata[] = "<!--nextpage--><!--tab_title:UNKNOWN-->\n[vb " . $id[1] . "]";

else if (preg_match('#http://www.megavideo.com/v/(.+)[&"\']#si', $match, $id))
     $edata[] = "<!--nextpage--><!--tab_title:MEGAVIDEO-->\n[megavideo " . $id[1] . "]";

    }

if (isset($edata[0])) {

$embeds = implode("\n", ($edata)); 

print $embeds;

}
    } 

?>
```

This outputs only:

```
[megavideo P5X0UOA267fb79acd04cdb29a057c3fa0066573a1]
```

Every other player embed I have matches. Anything that is in the flashvars area does not. 
..Whereas something like the megavideo embed does. As for using a HTML Parser, it's most likely too late for that.. Besides, I'd rather be a purist if I can help it. I appreciate any help, thanks!

..Hopefully some of this makes sense. Explaining; not so good at it. The patterns seem to be overlapping each other, at best guess. ..The goal is output all three of those matches, if possible.

-edit-

The `$patterns[] = '<embed[^>]+flashvars="(.*?)["\']';` pattern seems to be picking up the two embeds after all..

```
[1]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(174) "file=http://cerium.realitylapse.com/stream/bea352a230ebd36b52dc27d874f41f5a/4e3c5eca/default/xxxxx/xxxxx-lq.mp4&amp;plugins=ltas&amp;ltas.cc=inhldvymihzxqln&amp;provider=http"
[1]=>
string(177) "provider=http&amp;file=http://www.xxxxx.com/player9397/vb.php?id=TT175YivmF4y&amp;type=video&amp;backcolor=111111&amp;frontcolor=cccccc&amp;lightcolor=DE4949&amp;stretching=fill"
[2]=>
string(0) ""
```

That leaves me wondering what is causing the problem...

-edit-

Nevermind, I got it to work! ..Not sure exactly how though.

Comment: You have not written what you want to achieve and what fails. What do you want it to output?

Comment: All three matches, if possible..

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your method is that two of the embedings have both, a `src` attribute and a `flashvars` attribute. In both cases the `src` is the first one and will therefore be matched first.

Depending on the structure of your source (e.g. is `src` always before `flashvars`? are other attributes possible) you can use several approaches:

A) First try the most restrictive regex (i.e. in this case the `flashvars`) and if it fits, process the content. Otherwise try the next one (e.g. looking for `src`).

B) You can build a negative lookaround regex (will be quite complicated and almost unreadable) to match `src` only if no `flashvars` is included.

C) Parse all the attributes within you `embed` tag and process them within a loop.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but the src pattern seems to taking an extra quote at the end.. `<embed src="http://www.megavideo.com/v/xxxxx""` Anyways, that's how it appears with the `var_dump()`. ..Shouldn't it stop at the very first ending quote? Since the flashvars is not inside of the src, that shouldn't be what's causing the problem.. right? ..Nevermind, I'm not so sure that may be it anymore.

Comment: The extra quote is because `var_dump` encloses string into quotes again and this is just the closing quote of the variable and not part of the content.

Comment: ..Yeah, that's what it must be. But why is it showing that the matches created by the `var_dump` pattern are found? -edited the main post with it- ... Whoa.. It seems to be working now, for some reason!